# Cut and quantile in R in not including zero

Tags: r, cut, quantile, binning

I am trying to bin numeric data from a column in R based on the 1st, 3rd and 4th quantile ( ie. 0-25%, 25%-75%,75%-100%). I have used the following code but the zero do not get included in the binning. They are shown as NA.

```
rawdata1$usage4 <- cut(rawdata1$Usage_Percentage,
      breaks = quantile(rawdata1$Usage_Percentage,
      probs = c(-Inf,0.25,0.75,Inf),include.lowest=T),labels=F)
```

> Error in quantile.default(rawdata1$Usage_Percentage, probs = c(-Inf,
>   0.25,  :    'probs' outside [0,1]

However if use the following code and divide it into 4 quantiles, the bins are just fine.

```
rawdata1$usage5 <- cut(rawdata1$Usage_Percentage,
   breaks = quantile(rawdata1$Usage_Percentage),
   include.lowest=T,labels=F)
```

Comment: Did you try  `probs = c(0,0.25,0.75,1),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include zeros in the binning you can also use the `cut2` function from `Hmisc`. 
Here is an example.

```
data <- data.frame(vect = c(1.64, 1.5, 1.5, 1.41, 1.64, 1.64, 0, 1.45, 1.64, 1.5, 1.45, 0, 1.45, 1.64,
                            1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 0, 1.5, 1.41, 0.18, 0.09, 0.1, 0.09, 0.05, 0.09, 1.64, 1.5,
                            1.5, 0.1, 0.05, 0.09, 0, 5.82, 5.86, 5.86, 0, 5.82, 5.82, 5.82, 5.82, 5.82,
                            5.86, 5.86, 5.82, 0, 5.91, 9.41, 9.5, 5.91, 0, 9.45, 5.91, 9.45, 5.91, 0,
                            0, 9.55, 5.91, 9.55, 9.5, 9.55, 0, 5.82, 1.64))

data$bin <- factor(Hmisc::cut2(data$vect, g = 4), labels = c(1:4))
#g represents the number of quantile groups
```